# Alternative to AND and OR Operatos

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table calles "jugadores" and i want to select "name" and "salario", but only where "salario" is == to few numbers.

```
SELECT apellido,salario FROM jugadores WHERE salario = 130000 OR 130000 OR 60000 OR 4000
```

This is easy, my question is how do the same, but without using AND or OR operators.

Comment: Use the `in` operator.

Comment: "OR 130000" is always true. So is "OR 60000"!

Comment: Your query is not correct. It should read `salario=130000 OR salario=60000 OR salario=40000`. You can write it using `salario IN (130000, 60000, 40000)` but the improvement is only visual. It is the same query and it runs the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT 
    apellido,
    salario 
FROM 
    jugadores 
WHERE 
    salario IN (130000, 60000, 4000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use in operator

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this it will work :**

```
Use "IN" operator :
```

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT apellido,salario FROM jugadores WHERE salario IN(130000,60000,4000,..)
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: @LeaCohen, Thanks. I Updated..:)